# Can I whitelist tags in Python Markdown?

Tags: python, markdown

#### Question

I'd like to specify a list of tags to whitelist during conversion. For instance, if I only want to convert `<p>`, `<ol>`, `<li>`, and a few other tags, but ignore all others, then given a value like this:

```
### Header

This is a paragraph.

    # Code snippet
    def spam():
        pass

1. One
2. Two
3. Three
```

I would want that to be converted to exactly:

```
### Header

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

    # Code snippet
    def spam():
        pass

<ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

I realize I could use [Bleach](https://pypi.org/project/bleach/) to clean out tags I don't want, but I'd rather not convert them in the first place, if possible.

#### Note:

I'm referring to https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your can't "whitelist" tags, but you can use the [Extension API](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/api/) to alter various parts of the parser. However, you probably don't really want that anyway.

For example, if you don't want to have headers and code blocks parsed, you can remove those processors:

```
from markdown.extensions import Extension

class MyExtension(Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md):
        md.parser.blockprocessors.deregister('hashheader')
        md.parser.blockprocessors.deregister('setextheader')
        md.parser.blockprocessors.deregister('code')
```

However, that won't give you the desired result as the parser will fall back to wrapping that text in a `<p>` tag. In fact, that is inherent in the Markdown syntax. Anything that is not recognized as something else is considered to be a paragraph.

Therefore, your input would likely result in the following output:

```
<p>### Header</p>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<p>    # Code snippet
    def spam():
        pass</p>

<ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

A further complication is HTML's handling of "insignificant whitespace." Specifically, except when directly instructed not to (such as in a code block), all whitespace is condensed into a single space when rendering HTML in a browser. Therefore, your paragraph which contains the unparsed code block would be rather unreadable:

> # Code snippet
>       def spam():
>           pass

If that is not what you want, then you would likely need to replace the existing processors with your own custom processors which recognize code blocks and headers, but return something other than the default HTML to avoid them being wrapped in `<p>` tags. However, that would effectively involve replacing most of the parser.

Additionally, not being wrapped in any tags, the plain text would all get condensed into a single paragraph. For example, this input:

```
# Header 1

    # code snippet
    def spam():
        pass

## Header 2
```

Would be rendered like this this:

> # Header 1 # code snippet def spam(): pass ## Header 2

Which is probably not what you want. Wrapping the text in `<p>` tags is actually a more desirable result, as that would at least render as:

> # Header 1
>
> # Code snippet
>       def spam():
>           pass
>
> ## Header 2

By the way, This is why Markdown parsers don't provide a "whitelist" option. The results are never what those who want the option expect.

Full disclosure: I am the lead developer of the Python-Markdown project.